# isotope Combination filters with the Views Isotope Module?

Tags: views

Here is a link to the proof of concept: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html

So we know it is possible with Isotope. How do i accomplish this with the Views Isotope module?

I currently have two main Taxonomy, Genre and Style.  I am filtering by Style but also want to filter by Genre. Fore example, Genre 'Hip hop' with a 'West Coast' Style. Or 'R&B' Genre with a 'Soul' Style.

Any ideas how to do this?

Edit: there is this blog post explaining Views Isotope and they have a paragraph that talks about this but it makes no sense to me. Might help someone answer this: http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=3739

> "There are two obstacles to using this feature in a more widespread
>   manner throughout the site.  First, I have only recently figured out
>   how to implement multiple filter options.  For example, we might want
>   to filter our news stories by Discipline and Semester.  To do this, we
>   rewrite the sorting fields in our Grid display so that they all
>   display in one field.  Then, we create two Filter blocks, one for each
>   set of terms.  Implementing this across the site so that users can
>   sort by say, item type and vocabulary term, will make it more useful
>   to us."